# How to apply scheduling algorithms on eucalyptus or openstack instances

Tags: cloud, openstack, eucalyptus

How to apply scheduling algorithms on openstack or eucalyptus instances? I have worked with both openstack and eucalyptus instances. I need to know how scheduling algorithms are applied for these instances.Please i need answers.

Comment: what do you mean by scheduling?  scheduling or provisioning of instances?  queueing / cpu priority?  memory and cache priority?  something else?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about compute/volume scheduling filters.

If that is the case , I would like you to go through the existing default filters and understand their behaviour , So that you are not reinventing the wheel again.

Check out  `nova.scheduler.driver.Scheduler`  you can find out default filters.

If you really want to create a scheduler filter, then at high level you have to go through the below steps.

```
   1.  Inherit nova.scheduler.driver.Scheduler class
   2.  Override the methods - schedule_run_instance & select_destinations 
   3. Implement your logic 
   4. Update nova.conf to include the new class for scheduler_driver property 
   5. Restart nova-scheduler service
```

Check out the logs if there is no warnings/errors thrown.

This should work for openstack environment.